# What is the difference between rotational symmetry and spherical symmetry when deciding what type of triple integral to use?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

When deciding which type of triple integral to use to compute the volume of a shape, I am stuck on whether to use spherical or cylindrical coordinates. I read that you use spherical coordinates when a shape has spherical symmetry, and you use cylindrical coordinates when a shape has rotational symmetry. What do these mean? And can a shape have both?

Comment: You could say a sphere has much more rotational symmetry than a cylinder, since a cylinder is only rotationally symmetric about a single axis

Comment: I never really understood why spherical coordinates were named as such - the radius $r$ makes sense for a sphere, but the other two coordinates seem arbitrarily decided. I'm not saying I know of a better way to "coordinatize" a sphere, but spherical coordinates always seemed clunky to me

Comment: @Zubin: Any coordinate system deserving of the name "spherical" will necessarily be a little clunky, because there is no way to parametrize the surface of a sphere without at least one singularity. However, most of civilization has agreed that latitude and longitude are a reasonable way to do it, and that's essentially what the other two coordinates in spherical coordinates are, so you may be the odd one out here.

Comment: @Rahul [Geographical coordinates are apparently very different from spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#In_geography), the former uses "elevation angle" whereas the latter uses "inclination angle" ... I think [this web page](https://vvvv.org/blog/polar-spherical-and-geographic-coordinates) explains conversion between the two distinct coordinate systems quite well. It doesn't seem that latitude and longitude are "essentially what the other two coordinates are" in the spherical coordinate system, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: The second web page you linked you says "the conversion is quite simple: latitude = polar - 90°, longitude = azimuthal", which is what I meant by them being "essentially" the same. Of course there are various other complications due to the fact that the Earth is not actually a perfect sphere, as mentioned in the Wikipedia article, but I stand by my assertion that geographical and spherical coordinates are essentially the same and differ mainly in the choice of where to put the zero.

Answer (score 0):

As any rule of thumb, this rule can misfire. It is ultimately about which type of integral will end up being simpler to calculate. (Normally it happens if you can quickly eliminate at least one variable from the calculation.) If in doubt, try both. Do a few examples and build up experience.

I have actually tried to write up a more detailed answer with rules of the type "if this - do that", but have realised half-way that I would be doing you a disservice. Namely, it would make the rule complicated enough so that, in time you would use to decide whether to use cylindrical or spherical co-ordinates - you could easily try out both.